# Get info from another window in Caliburn.Micro, WPF, MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, caliburn.micro

Im making Login Window in my app based on Caliburn.Micro mvvm framework. So, how to return an property (for example, `true` if user passed good data or `false`, if he pass bad credentials) from `TryClose()` method from my Login Window that is initialize by Caliburn.Micro? How to get information from window opened in `IWindowManager.ShowDialog()`?

First, my **MainWindowViewModel.cs**:

```
using Caliburn.Micro;

namespace TaskManager.ViewModels
{
    class MainWindowViewModel : Conductor<IScreen>.Collection.OneActive
    {
        protected override void OnViewLoaded(object view)
        {
            IWindowManager manager = new WindowManager();
            //Login page, context is data with user's lists
            LoginViewModel loginView = new LoginViewModel(context);
            manager.ShowDialog(loginView, null, null);
            //here i want to get info, if i get logged properly or not
        }

        public void LoadUserInfoPage() //here starts "main" program
        {
            ActivateItem(new UserInfoViewModel());
        }
        //and so on...
    }
```

}

My **LoginViewModel.cs**:

```
namespace TaskManager.ViewModels
{
class LoginViewModel : Screen
{
    public string Login    { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }

    public LoginViewModel(FakeData context)
    {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public void LoginButton()
    {
        bool check = Services.Login.IsValid(Login, Password, context);
        if(check) //if login is OK, check == true
            TryClose();
    }

    private FakeData context { get; set; } //data is here
}
}
```

Then, my `IsValid()` Method:

```
namespace TaskManager.Services
{
static class Login
{
    static public bool IsValid(string login, string password, FakeData context) 
        => context.users.Any(i => i.Login == login);
        //i know it is bad, but its only example
}
}
```

Buttons, opening and closing windows works great (reading from textboxes too). I want only get info (maybe by reference?) if user is pass good data.

THanks for your advices!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of EventAggregator for the purpose.

> "An Event Aggregator is a service that provides the ability to publish
>   an object from one entity to another in a loosely based fashion. "

The first step would be create instance of EventAggregator in your ViewModels and subscribe to it. You can do it via DI in constructor of both ViewModels.

For LoginViewModel,

```
private IEventAggregator _eventAggregator;
public LoginViewModel(FakeData context,IEventAggregator eventAggregator)
{
    _eventAggregator = eventAggregator;
}
```

And MainWindowViewModel,

```
private IEventAggregator _eventAggregator;
public MainWindowViewModel (IEventAggregator eventAggregator)
{
_eventAggregator = eventAggregator;
_eventAggregator.Subscribe(this);
}
```

The next step is to create a Message Object, which can transmit the required information between the ViewModels.

```
public class OnLoginAttemptMessage
{
    string UserName { get; set; }
    bool IsLoginSuccessful { get; set; }
}
```

Finally, it is time to put everything together. In youg LoginButton method in LoginViewModel, we modify the code to raise the event on successfull login.

```
public void LoginButton()
{
  bool check = Services.Login.IsValid(Login, Password, context);
  if(check) //if login is OK, check == true
  {
    _eventAggregator.PublishOnUIThread(new OnLoginAttemptMessage
    {
      UserName = Login,
      IsLoginSuccessful = check;
    });
    TryClose();
   }
 }
```

The last step is in MainWindowViewModel, where you need to implement the IHandle interface.

```
class MainWindowViewModel : Conductor<IScreen>.Collection.OneActive, IHandle<OnLoginSuccessMessage>
{

        public void Handle(OnLoginSuccessMessage message)
        {
            if(message.IsLoginSuccessful)
            {
                // Login is successfull, do next steps.
            }
        } 
}
```

You can read more on EventAggregator here (https://caliburnmicro.com/documentation/event-aggregator)

Comment: I can transfer like this anything i want? Strings, ints etc?

Comment: Yes you can. Any structure your define in them message class can be transferred

Comment: Hi, i posted another question in Caliburn.micro. I will be glad if you could look on it :D

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53706176/caliburn-micro-wpf-and-two-comboboxes