# Caliburn.micro, WPF and two comboboxes

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, caliburn.micro

I want to solve Master -> Detail problem with my Caliburn.Micro + wpf project.

I have two `comboboxes` coded like this in **TaskManagerView.xaml**:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="ProjectsList" SelectedValuePath="{Binding Path=SelectedProjectsList, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />

<ComboBox x:Name="TasksList"/>
```

The first Combobox `ProjectsList` works ok, i can get what i want to. Second is a little complicated. I get `SelectedProjectList` correctly (while im debuging on button i see what i choose). `ProjectsList` are the name of projects from `new Project()` class. In `Project` i store list of `Task`. But when i want to fill `TasksList`, i get exception.

Now, my **TaskManagerViewModel**:

```
    class TaskManagerViewModel : Screen //constructor of ViewModel
    {
        public BindableCollection<string> ProjectsList { get; set; } //first CB
        public BindableCollection<string> TasksList { get; set; } //secondCB
        public string SelectedProjectsList { get; set; }//selected item from first combobox

        public TaskManagerViewModel(FakeData context) //constructor
        {
            this.context = context;
            //it works fine, i get Project.Name here from List<Project>
            ProjectsList = context.GetProjectsName();

            //i selected project name from combobox,
            //now i want to get tasks stored in List<Project> 
            //where SelectedProjectsList == Project.Name
            tasks = context.GetProjectsTasks(SelectedProjectsList); 
            foreach (Task task in tasks)
            {
                TasksList.Add(task.TaskName);
                NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => TasksList);
            }
        }


        public void CancelButton() => TryClose();

        private FakeData context;
        private List<Task> tasks;
    }
```

My question is, where and how code helper function for getting `List<Task>'s` names? I know that i done here is bad because i do everything in construcotr of ViewModel but i want to show u, what i want to do.

For now, i getting `NullReferenceException`, because `SelectedProjectsList` is null. How to rise up event on selected item from `ComboBox`? I choose project name and i immediately want to have tasks from choosen project (i know i can do it from button easily but its not what i want to achive)

Thanks for any advices!

**Edit:**

Of course if i edit VM to this form:

```
class TaskManagerViewModel : Screen
{
    public BindableCollection<string> ProjectsList { get; set; }
    public BindableCollection<string> TasksList{ get; set; }
    public string SelectedProjectsList { get; set; }

    public TaskManagerViewModel(FakeData context)
    {
        this.context = context;
        ProjectsList = context.GetProjectsName();
        TasksList = new BindableCollection<string>();
        //i moved initializing new combobox to AcceptButton()
    }

    public void AcceptButton()
    {
        //initializing tasks list on button click
        tasks = context.GetProjectsTasks(SelectedProjectsList);
        TasksList = new BindableCollection<string>();
        foreach (Task task in tasks)
        {
            TasksList.Add(task.TaskName);
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => TasksList);
        }
    }

    public void CancelButton() => TryClose();

    private FakeData context;
    private List<Task> tasks;
}
```

What i want to do is choose item from first combobox and immidietly tasks list in second shows up. I dont want to Choose item from first combobox, click on button and then choose item from second combobox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As this is MVVM, your ViewModel does not know about combo boxes or their events, so you can't subscribe to the control's event directly.

When you select an item in projects list, it sets a value to SelectedProjectsList property, you can use this:

```
private string _selectedProjectsList;
public string SelectedProjectsList
{
    get
    {
        return _selectedProjectsList;
    }
    set
    {
        _selectedProjectsList = value;
        // project selection has been changed, populate your task list now!
        // upd: actual code for populating the list
        tasks = context.GetProjectsTasks(SelectedProjectsList);
        TasksList = new BindableCollection<string>();
        foreach (Task task in tasks)
        {
            TasksList.Add(task.TaskName);
        }
        NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => TasksList);
    }
}
```

Comment: Look on my edit please, your answer is not about my question but i give u +1 for trying, thanks!

Comment: I still don't see how this does not answer your question. When your user selects an item in project list combobox, your SelectProjectsList property will be set. If you overload your setter, you can populate your tasks list combobox immediately.

Comment: This is what this solution does: it "listens" to set on SelectedProjectsList. Could you please be more specific on that "not working" part. What exactly is not working?

Comment: Sorry for that, i didnt see u edited your answer. It works great now, thanks! But why when i try to work on `SelectedProjectLists` (`get { return this.SelectedProjectLists }` etc...) i get `StackOverflowException`? Using private propertys seems pretty oldschool right now

Comment: The reason you get StackOverflowException is that by calling "return this.SelectedProjectLists" you actually call SelectedProjectsList's getter again. Which calls it again. Which calls it again. And so on and so forth until there is no stack left. Auto-properties is just a syntax sugar; too much sugar might be bad for your health.